# Get number by knowing chance

Tags: php, arrays

I don't think the article title is correct so I will try to explain what I need.

ATM I have array:

```
array(
      'start'         => 1,
      'end'           => 10,
      'lucky_numbers' => 6
   );
```

and knowing this array I can define that chance to win is 60% out of 100%. The next part is the second array:

```
array(0, 1.25, 0.5, 1.25, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0.5, 1.25, 0.5, 1.25, 0, 2, 0.5, 2)
```

and this is the hard part. I don't have any clue how to pick one number knowing that chance to pick not a zero is 60%. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

this is the wheel numbers. when user spins the wheel i need to give him 60% chance to win. So 60% chance to spin not the 0

Comment: exactly how does this second array relate to the first?

Comment: the first array defines that chance to win is 60% (6 of 10 numbers are lucky). So looking at the second array we should know that chance get zero is only 40%

Comment: Still confused, what do you want to do with the second array? You want to know which number is 60% of the greatest number in the fields?

Comment: I think he wants to be able to prick a number between 1 and 10, with 6 of those numbers being randomly correct, but i still don't get the second array..

Comment: I agree the question is very confusing, probably much harder then the actual answer

Comment: this is the wheel numbers. when user spins the wheel i need to give him 60% chance to win. So 60% chance to spin not the 0 - i think this will help you guys to understand

Comment: How about add an expected output, as in the second example, what do you want the output to be

Comment: If it's a "pick a lucky number game", I don't expect the player to get "1.25" as a result. Unless you're coding a game for mathematicians :)

Comment: this is a game - to multiple your wager.

Comment: @ArnasPečelis You have numbers from `0` to `3` in your second array, so you want to choose which number is 60% from these ranges? which would be `1.8` or its nearest number, and not a float .. so that would output `2` as a 60% lucky?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if i understand:

-This is a "slots like" winnings multiplier minigame for a game where you roll a "wheel" showing the possibles multipliers the player can win, this wheel is the second array, this array is variable in lenght.

-You want to give the player a variable chance to win (sometimes 60%, sometimes 80%, sometimes 20%).

If you only want to be sure the player doesn't get a "0%" multiplier, do the opposite, take the possibility of a "0%" to appear and put them the equivalent in the array and then fill the array with random multipliers and shuffle it.

```
$multipliers = [0.5, 1.25, 2, 3];
$wheel = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $arraylenght; $i++) {
    if ($i < floor($arraylenght * (1 - ((float)$luckyNumbers/10)))){
        $wheel[] = 0;
    } else {
        $wheel[] = array_rand($multipliers);
    }
}
shuffle($wheel);
```

Now if you also want to control the probabilities of each multiplier... That's another beast.

Comment: You are the man. And you are going good  direction. The problem with another beast - I solved it. My code not looks perfect but here it is: [link](http://i.imgur.com/qNxpUAm.png) - the logic is the same I think so, but your code should work much faster then mine!